# How can I generate a matrix with random values based from a larger matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation

I would like to know if there was a way to generate a matrix with values based from a larger matrix. For example, if I have

```
larger_matrix = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,5))

Out[1]: 
array([[0, 9, 0, 0, 3],
       [9, 4, 7, 7, 0],
       [9, 4, 5, 6, 9],
       [6, 3, 1, 7, 3],
       [8, 4, 6, 9, 7],
       [8, 1, 5, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 6, 0, 9],
       [9, 9, 6, 8, 7],
       [5, 5, 6, 6, 4],
       [4, 4, 7, 0, 7]])
```

and I want to create `smaller_matrix` of size (4, 5), with values randomly sampled from `larger_matrix`, how should I go about this? I'm aware that the function `np.random.choice()` exists, but I'm quite unsure if it would be helpful for my problem because I'm dealing with matrices instead of lists. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `flatten` to convert 2d `larger_matrix` to 1d.
2. Then you can use `random.choice` to get random sample from `larger_matrix`
3. Finally, use `reshape` to convert 1d list to 2d matrix

#### code:

```
import numpy as np
larger_matrix = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,5))
print(larger_matrix)
n = 4
m = 5
print(np.reshape(np.random.choice(larger_matrix.flatten(),size = n*m),(n,m)))
```

#### result:

```
[[7 4 4 6 0]
 [5 7 0 6 8]
 [9 9 0 0 5]
 [9 8 0 6 7]
 [0 9 8 8 1]
 [3 7 1 0 0]
 [8 9 2 3 8]
 [6 3 7 2 9]
 [9 7 5 9 3]
 [8 8 3 5 8]]

[[0 0 8 0 9]
 [6 9 2 7 0]
 [8 7 6 0 7]
 [7 4 9 3 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a for loop inside a for loop and use it to fill the smaller matrix with random indexes from the matrix.
`For i in range(len(larger_matrix)): For j in range(len(larger_matrix[0])): smaller_matrix[i][j] = larger_matrix[rand1][rand2]` 
That should cover it. Just make sure you generate 2 new numbers each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this but bear in mind that the choices taken from the large array may be duplicated:-

```
import numpy as np
import random
R1 = 10
R2 = 4
C = 5
m = np.random.randint(R1, size=(R1, C))
print(m)
print()
n = []
for _ in range(R2):
    n.append(random.choice(m))
print(np.array(n))
```